# Arithmetic overflow converting to int when inserting 2,147,483,648 or greater into decimal(18,6) column in SQL Server database table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, decimal, arithmetic-overflow

I am experiencing this issue in SQL Server 2012 but it is also manifest in SQL Server 2017.

My database table, call it `MyTable`, contains a `decimal(18,6)` column, `new_balance`, which is not nullable. The table also contains two integer columns which are part of the primary key. There are no other integer fields.

A stored procedure has a parameter `@new_balance` which is also defined as `decimal(18,6)`. There are also parameters for id (`@id`) and seq_num (`@seq_num`), both defined as `int`.

The procedure carries out an insert into the table along the lines of:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, seq_num, new_balance)
VALUES (@id, @seq_num, @new_balance);
```

When `@new_balance` is set to 2147483647.999999 or lower, the insert proceeds as expected.
When `@new_balance` is set to a number greater than or equal to 2147483648, e.g. 2147483648.1, the procedure fails with an arithmetic overflow converting expression to int error. I appreciate that the max value for an int column is 2147483647.

This is also the case using the following insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, seq_num, new_balance)
SELECT @id, @seq_num, @new_balance;
```

Given that both the parameter and table column are defined as `decimal(18,6)`, I am struggling to see why there is a conversion to int as part of the insert (especially with the second statement where I wouldn't expect any implicit conversion).

I have also tried to cast `@new_balance` to `decimal(18,6)` explicitly as part of the `INSERT` statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, seq_num, new_balance)
SELECT @id, @seq_num, CAST(@new_balance AS decimal(18,6));
```

This also didn't work.

Strangely it works fine if I specify in a query a table variable with the same definitions and carry out a similar insert:

```sql
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (id int, seq_num int, new_balance decimal(18,6));
INSERT INTO @MyTable (id, seq_num, new_balance)
SELECT @id, @seq_num, @new_balance;
```

I have tried this approach in the procedure, i.e. first inserting the record into `@MyTable` and then trying to insert into `MyTable` as follows:

```sql
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (id int, seq_num int, new_balance decimal(18,6));
INSERT INTO @MyTable (id, seq_num, new_balance) SELECT @id, @seq_num, @new_balance;
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, seq_num, new_balance) SELECT id, seq_num, new_balance FROM @MyTable;
```

This didn't work either.

For completeness, I also tried to create the record with a value of zero and then update the existing record - again this was unsuccessful and so this issue occurs with both an INSERT and an UPDATE:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, seq_num, new_balance) SELECT @id, @seq_num, 0.00;
```

This is fine - but the next step gives the same error as reported above:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable SET new_balance = @new_balance WHERE id = @id AND seq_num = @seq_num;
```

To confirm, there is no `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger or `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on the table - there are no triggers of any sort.

Change tracking is not enabled on the database and there are no constraints for this particular field - there are default constraints on other decimal(18,6) fields that feature in the actual table.

There have also been no views added to the database.

My first question on this forum - hopefully someone will have experienced this themselves and may know how to resolve it although I couldn't find a question of a similar nature. I'm stumped.

Comment: Find the dependencies on this table using SSMS. Perhaps there is an indexed view? And again verify that you are looking at the correct database / schema / object and that it has no INSERT triggers (you wrote it has no AFTER UPDATE trigger).

Comment: `To confirm, there is no INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger or AFTER UPDATE trigger` - what about the other types of triggers?

Comment: Does `MyTable` have Change Tracking enabled? Perhaps the data type of new_balance has changed from `int` to `decimal(18,6)` since CT was enabled. Unlike CDC (which is a Log Reader Agent process) CT happens in the context of the user transaction.

Comment: What about check constraints that might be using a scalar function for some sort of validation?

Comment: Cheers for the responses.  To confirm, @GSerg - there are no triggers of any kind that have been added to the table.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - the database does not have Change Tracking enabled.

Comment: @bbaird - there are no constraints for this particular field - there are defaults of 0.00 for other decimal(18,6) fields on the table and there is also a FK to its parent table keyed on id, seq_num.

Comment: @SMor - there are no triggers on the table and there are no views set up in the database.

Comment: Any computed column in MyTable?

Comment: @Arvo - there are no computed columns in MyTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having been able to insert directly into the table outside of the procedure, I looked at some of the downstream events and identified the issue:

After inserting the record, the system updates the status of the associated record in a parent table.  There is an AFTER UPDATE on this parent table which identifies this status change as requiring audit and runs a secondary procedure to create the audit history records.  As part of this capture, the system converts the old and new values in MyTable to a user-friendly format using a scalar-valued function.  As part of this, the value is split into two parts to create the necessary formatting and the whole number part was being cast as an int.  By changing this cast to bigint, the issue resolved itself.

The premise of the original question was therefore wrong - the issue lay several layers down.

Thanks to those who contributed.